# Angular 4 call function in another component

Tags: angular

I have a search bar in a header component, that are supposed to search in a list in another component. How do i get the headerComponent to call a function in the BooksComponent?

```
export class HeaderComponent {
    search(){
        searchBooks($(".header-search-input").val());
    }
}


export class BooksComponent {

  searchBooks(searchWord){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the `search()` function to a service and inject it into the component that need this function.

**search.service.ts**

```
@Injectable
export class SearchService {
  search() {
    ...
  }
}
```

**Injection**

```
import { SearchService } from './search.service.ts';

export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(public searchService SearchService) {}

  search() {
    this.searchService.search();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to create a service and there use event emitter.

**Book.service.ts**

```
export class BookService {
    search = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

**Header Component**

```
export class headerComponent() {
   constructor(private bookService:BookService) {}

   search() {
       this.bookService.search.emit($(".header-search-input").val());
   }
}
```

**Book Component**

```
export class BookComponent {
    constructor(private bookService:BookService) {
        //Catch the event to make the search
        this.bookService.search.subscribe(value => {
             this.searchBooks(searchWord);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create service with property type of Subject. Then inject it in both components. In HeaderComponent call Subject.next(val) when value in input change, in BooksComponent subscribe to this subject and call rest api.
Service with subject should be provided on module which declare both components.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you should understand there is no way to call or access data from     another `component` from the current `component`.
2. By using the `Input`,`Output` attributes only the components will be interact     each other.
3. By Passing the input parameter as a child component by using Input attribute you can perform some operation on `child component`.
4. If you want to perform operation on `parent component` you should
   use `Output` with `event emitter`.

I hope this will help you.